# Swagger 2 annotations - meaningful schema example for maps

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

This is pretty much the same as [this other question for Swagger 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50607691/display-custom-hashmap-key-using-swagger-annotations), except it's related to Swagger 2.

In short, I have an implementation i'm trying to annotate in order to generate an OpenApi 3 spec. One of the models has a map property, and I want to generate a nice meaningful sample for it.

For example, looking at the [containerCreate Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.25/#operation/ContainerCreate), under `HostConfig`, there's a `PortBindings` object, which has one entry `"22/tcp"`:

```
{
    "HostConfig": {
        "PortBindings": {
          "22/tcp": [    <== niceeee
            {
              "HostPort": "11022"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the doc generated from my sources is somewhat similar but less useful. While the `PortBinding` example is correct and helpful, the `"additionalProp1"` doesn't really mean anything:

```
{
    "HostConfig": {
        "PortBindings": {
          "additionalProp1": [    <== not so nice
            {
              "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
              "HostPort": "8080"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

**`HostConfig`** implementation

```
@Schema(description = "Container configuration that depends on the host we are running on")
public class HostConfig implements Serializable {
    @Schema(description = "A map of exposed container ports and the host port they should map to.")
    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("PortBindings")
    private Map<String, List<PortBinding>> portBindings;
}
```

**`PortBinding`** implementation

```
@Schema(description = "Host IP and port to which to bind a container port")
public class PortBindingDefinition implements Serializable {
    @Schema(description = "The host IP address", nullable = true, example = "127.0.0.1")
    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("HostIp")
    private String hostIp;

    @Schema(description = "The host port number, as a string", example = "8080")
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("HostPort")
    private String hostPort;
}
```

---

I can paste a json in there as an example, but this seems more of a hack, and it has to be kept in sync with the structure of the actual objects that are in the map:

```
@Schema(description = "A map of exposed container ports and the host port they should map to.",
        example = "{\"PortBindings\": {\"22/tcp\": [{\"HostPort\": \"11022\"}]}}")
```

Other than that I can't figure out how to achieve the same, and the [Swagger examples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#schema) haven't been of too much help so far.

---

Bottom line, is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score -2):

I made some research on this topic and came to no satisfying conclusion either.
The documentation of the `@Schema.pattern` field ([here](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#example--)) states:

> When associated with a specific media type, the example string shall
> be parsed by the consumer to be treated as an object or an array.

So I assume your "hack" is the only way to go..